# InteractiveViewer panEnabled is not working in ternary operator condition

Tags: flutter

I got a trouble with InteractiveViewer Widget with panEnabled method.

The function I want to implement is when I click the `PenWidget`, `_memoMode` changes to `true` and `panEnabled` becomes `false` and InteractiveViewer UI stuck and doesn't move. (panEnabled becomes false)

But when the `_memoMode` is changed to true, still panning is possible.

is using ternary operator in `panEnabled` is wrong? or how can I make the widget to zoomable and when `_memoMode` is false, panning is impossible not using InteractiveViewer?

here's my code

```
class WorkbookViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String downloadedURL;
  String workbookName;

  WorkbookViewPage(this.downloadedURL, this.workbookName, {super.key});

  @override
  State<WorkbookViewPage> createState() => _WorkbookViewPageState();
}

class _WorkbookViewPageState extends State<WorkbookViewPage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;
  int _lastClosedPage = 1;

  bool _memoMode = false;

  // Widget Key
  GlobalKey _viewKey = GlobalKey();

  // pen size control widget Entry
  bool isOverlayVisible = false;
  OverlayEntry? entry;

  // Listener for stylus
  bool isPenTouched = false;

  /// Hide Overlay Widget
  void hideOverlay() {
    entry?.remove();
    entry = null;
    isOverlayVisible = false;
  }

  /// get Last closed page of workbook
  void _loadLastClosedPage() async {
    final pagePrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _lastClosedPage = pagePrefs.getInt('${widget.workbookName}') ?? 1;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
    String workbookName = '${widget.workbookName}';
    _loadLastClosedPage();
    print("======== Loaded workbook name = ${workbookName} ==========");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Drawing Provider
    var p = context.read<DrawingProvider>();

    /// set _lastClosedPage
    void countLastClosedPage() async {
      final pagePrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
        pagePrefs.setInt('${widget.workbookName}', _lastClosedPage);
        _lastClosedPage = (pagePrefs.getInt('${widget.workbookName}') ?? 1);
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: buildPenFuncWidgets(p, hideOverlay, context),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        panEnabled: _memoMode ? false : true,
        maxScale: 3,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: true,
              child: SfPdfViewer.network(
                widget.downloadedURL,
                controller: _pdfViewerController,
                key: _pdfViewerKey,
                pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
                enableDoubleTapZooming: false,
                // Save the last closed page number
                onPageChanged: (details) {
                  _lastClosedPage = details.newPageNumber;
                  countLastClosedPage();
                },
                onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
                  _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(_lastClosedPage);
                },
              ),
            ),

            //  PDF view under drawing layer
            WorkbookDrawingPage(),
            //buildPenFuncWidgets(p, hideOverlay, context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> buildPenFunctionWidget build method

```
  Container buildPenFuncWidgets(
      DrawingProvider p, void Function() hideOverlay, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.white),
      height: 50,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: () {
             // When Touch the PenWidget button, function 'changePenMode' which in the Drawing 
             // Provider Class is called and _memoMode becomes true 
             // 

                p.changePenMode();
                _memoMode = p.penMode;
                print("_memoMode = ${_memoMode}");
              },
              child: PenWidget(p: p)),



void changePenMode() {
    _penMode = !_penMode;
    // _selectedColor = _selectedColor.withOpacity(1);
    print("penMode is called : ${penMode} ");
    _eraseMode = false;
    _highlighterMode = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: when calling `_memoMode = p.penMode;` you have to call `setState` too

Comment: @pskink Thank you! I fixed it, It doesn't panning !  I thought setState cannot be in the onTap method.